# Examples for using Apache UIMA in a java program

Tags: java, apache, uima

I have been searching for examples of using Apache UIMA in a java program. Are there examples on how to use the example Annotators in a Java program ?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use UIMA directly into Java code, you might want to have a look at [uimafit](https://code.google.com/p/uimafit/), because it eases the use of UIMA from within Java. Here is a quick example to use the example Annotator ([source](https://code.google.com/p/uimafit/source/browse/trunk/uimaFIT-examples/src/main/java/org/uimafit/examples/tutorial/ex1/RoomNumberAnnotatorPipeline.java))

```
public class RoomNumberAnnotatorPipeline {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws UIMAException {
                String text = "The meeting was moved from Yorktown 01-144 to Hawthorne 1S-W33.";
                TypeSystemDescription tsd = createTypeSystemDescription(
                                "org.uimafit.examples.tutorial.type.RoomNumber");
                JCas jCas = createJCas(tsd);
                jCas.setDocumentText(text);

                AnalysisEngine analysisEngine = createPrimitive(RoomNumberAnnotator.class, tsd);
                analysisEngine.process(jCas);

                for (RoomNumber roomNumber : select(jCas, RoomNumber.class)) {
                        System.out.println(roomNumber.getCoveredText() + "\tbuilding = "
                                        + roomNumber.getBuilding());
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: a little late, but one shortcoming is uimafit doesn't support pear packages.

Comment: @goh try with https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/uimafit-users/daWLysnrfHI

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are examples provided in UIMA SDK. You need to read developers guide here how to view the source in Eclipse.[UIMA Tutorial and Dev Guide](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.4.0/overview_and_setup.html#ugr.project_overview_tutorials_dev_guides). Look at section 1.1.3 and Chapter 3.